# How to find the biggest number using only two-way branching

Tags: c++, if-statement, max

I need help in solving my C++ problem exercise. The problem is this, I have to input 3 numbers and output the biggest number but I only need to use the two-way branching (if else). Can you help me with this?

Comment: Using [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) would be the *sensible* way to solve that problem.

Comment: @Harold Cuico And what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The usual difficulty is initializing the maximum starter point with a small number. You can overcome it by reading the very first number into the result:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int max, curr;
    std::cin >> max;
    for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i) {
        std::cin >> curr;
        if (curr > max) {
            max = curr;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Max: " << max << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This code does not enetrs three numbers and only after that finds the biggest number.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am sorry, couldn't quite understand your comment. Wasn't the question about finding maximum? Is the problem the fact that numbers come from the standard input? The question states "I have to input 3 numbers"

Comment: I think that these actions, to input three numbers and to find the biggest number, should be sequenced.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is this what OP specifically asked for? This version scales more easily and saves memory for larger number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, even if you cannot use [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) (which would be the usual go-to solution).

Assuming the numbers are integers and there are only 3 and we can only use `if`, this (simple/stupid) solution should do it:

```
int max_num = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

if (num1 > max_num) { max_num = num1; }
if (num2 > max_num) { max_num = num2; }
if (num3 > max_num) { max_num = num3; }

std::cout << "The maximum number is " << max_num << '\n';
```

Comment: It is just a bad approach.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I *did* say that it was stupid. But it *is* simple. And sometimes (often) simple is better than clever.

Comment: This initializer in this declaration int max_num = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); is redundant. See the second example in my answer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl why not initialize `max_num` with `num1`?

Comment: @Ayxan No reason really.

Answer (score 0):

If to use only if-else statements then the code can look like

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    std::cout << "Enter three integer numbers: ";

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

    int biggest = c;

    if ( not ( a < b ) and not ( a < c ) )
    {
        biggest = a;
    }
    else if ( not ( b < c ) )
    {
        biggest = b;
    }

    std::cout << "The biggest number is " << biggest << '\n';
}
```

The program output might be

```
Enter three integer numbers: 1 3 2 
The biggest number is 3
```

Another approach is the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    std::cout << "Enter three integer numbers: ";

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

    int biggest = a;

    if ( biggest < b )
    {
        biggest = b;
    }

    if (  biggest < c )
    {
        biggest = c;
    }

    std::cout << "The biggest number is " << biggest << '\n';
}
```